# plot multiple curves with color based on a color map in GNUPLOT

Tags: colors, gnuplot

Here is the problem I am having with GNUPLOT: I have data files with two columns each (one for the voltage the other for the current) and each obtained for a certain temperature (which is specified in their name something like iv_300K.dat, iv_290K.dat etc.).

Now what I want is to plot each data file on the same graph and each plot to have a colour based on the file name (I would like to show you a figure I made with Mathematica but it seems that my reputation is too low...)

So lets say I have iv_300K.dat, iv_250K.dat and iv_160K.dat I would like to have three curves coloured first red, second green-ish and third blue, but based on the temperature information in the file name.

I am thinking something similar to what I did in Mathematica:

```
ColorData["DarkRainbow"][Rescale[T, {160, 350}]]
```

Where `"DarkRainbow"` is a colormap and `Rescale[x,{min,max}]`
gives x rescaled to run from 0 to 1 over the range min to max (according the Mathematica documentation).

So `Rescale[250,{160,350}] = 0.473684`

At the moment in GNUPLOT I am using the following for testing purposes:

```
plot for [i=350:160:-10] 'iv_'.i.'.K.dat' using 1:2 with lines title sprintf("".i." K")
```

but I can't get the colours to map the temperature.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `linecolor palette frac` to select a color from a palette based on an value in the range [0:1]:

```
set cbrange [160:350]
set style data lines
plot for [i=350:160:-10] 'iv_'.i.'.K.dat' using 1:2 linecolor palette frac (i-160.0)/(350.0-160.0) title sprintf("%dK", i)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have just tried it but unfortunately I am getting the following error: Not enough columns for variable color. I have no idea where this is coming from.

Comment: I got it! it should be frac instead of frace! It works! Sweet! Now I don't mean to seem ungrateful but how can I change the color scheme to go from blue to red?

Comment: Got this as well! I found this resource here: https://github.com/Gnuplotting/gnuplot-palettes and I copy and pasted the description of the palette I wanted (jet in this case) at the beginning of my script and it works!

Comment: I have one more question: how can I add the unit next to the numbers in the legend on the right? I want to have it displayed something like 340 K, 250 K etc

Comment: That is already contained in my answer: `title sprintf("%d K", i)`

Comment: Unfortunately that one doesn't work! The K does not appear, only the numbers. I figured that was where the labeling is done but I can't seem to make it work. I don't really understand how sprintf works.

Comment: That definitely works, just do a `print sprintf("%d K", 100)` in the gnuplot command prompt, and it will print you "100 K" on the screen. The same result goes into the title. Run only the three lines I posted plus a `reset` before them and you must see the `K` appearing.

Comment: Well it appears as a legend on the plot but not along the color legend on the right of the plot. This is what I would like. I am sorry to abuse of your help! Your solution is spot on!

Comment: Ah, that's what you mean. Use `set cbtics format '%g K'`